# Not displaying continues data of networkstream in DataGridView

Tags: sockets, c#-4.0, network-programming, ethernet

Able to read the data from device through TcpClient class and method is below.

once i made the connection using Ipaddress and port through ethernet connection able to read the bytes of data. My read method reading networkstream data of particular number of bytes 
and trimming the string as my need and updating to a database and trying to show the updated data in datagridview.It will not displaying any data in datagridview.

can any one suggest how can i do this?

added code:

```
            private void ReceiveMethod()
           {
           try
          {
               string IP1 = textIP.Text.Trim();
               string port1 = textPort.Text.Trim(); 
               int port = Convert.ToInt32(port1);
               NetworkStream ns;
               int bytesRead = 0;
               byte[] buffer = new byte[9];

            try
            {

                IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(Ip1);
                client = new TcpClient();
                client.Connect(IP1, port);
                while (true)
               {
                    ns = client.GetStream();
                    ns.Read(buffer, (int)bytesRead, buffer.Length - (int)bytesRead);

                      ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                     msg = encoder.GetString(buffer);
                     GetData(msg);                        

                }
                client.Close();         

            }


    GetData(string data)
    {

       I'm trimming the data value according to my need
       and the updateing one filed of db and trying to populate table data in gridview

      //if i remove the while(true) in the Receivemethod am able to view the data in
         datagridview but i want to read continuous data from network stream and want 
         to show updated data in datagrid view
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you did not convert your networkstream data into sring and all data is converted DataRow class.

1. What Database do you use? (SQL Server/Oracle)
2. In what type of data do you put your networkstream data?
3. Show you code where you fill in your DGV.

Comment: try to see what type of data you have by compiler. If it is okay, then you should see code of fill in DGV.

Comment: I've edited the above post with code.only once it will appear,if i want to run continuosly then doesnt show any thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
  foreach(NetworkStream s in ns)
   {
      GetData(string data);
   }
```

Comment: if this answer is helpful, please vote. It is give motivation to answer:).